# Get static value from changing Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I'm creating a game with P5.js and regular javascript. I have falling objects (in an array) that, when collided with the mouse, return to the top of the screen.

I want to add a score number at the position of the collision.
How do I store the last known coordinate of that object to let the score number stay there for a while?

Live prototype can be seen here: http://www.getelonto.space (press any key to start the game)

I've searched all of the internet but found no luck.

```
//The array in the setup

function setup() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfMeteors; i++) {
    meteors[i] = {
      x: random(windowWidth-100),
      y: -1* random(windowHeight),

      display: function(){
        image(meteorimg, this.x, this.y);
    },
      fall: function(){
        this.y += random(1,15);
      }
    }   
  }
}

//The array in the draw

function meteor() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfMeteors; i++) {
      meteors[i].display();
      meteors[i].fall();

    //Mouse collision
    if (meteors[i].x < (mouseX+100) && meteors[i].x > (mouseX-175) && 
        meteors[i].y > (750) && meteors[i].y < (850)||
       (meteors[i].x < (mouseX+50) && meteors[i].x > (mouseX-100) && 
        meteors[i].y > (630) && meteors[i].y <= (750))) {

      // Attempt at getting the coordinates at collision
      var minScoreIndicatorX = meteors[i].x;
      var minScoreIndicatorY = meteors[i].y;


      //This is the score text I want to show
      text("-3", minScoreIndicatorX, minScoreIndicatorY);

      // Actions when collided
      score-=3;
      Lives = Lives-1;
      meteors[i].y = -1* (random(300));
      meteors[i].x = (random(windowWidth)-100);
      bgY2-=10;
      if (start==false) {
        meteors[i].y = 0;
      }
    }

    // Meteors returning to the top without collision
    if (meteors[i].y>windowHeight) {
      meteors[i].y = -1* (random(600));
      meteors[i].x = (random(windowWidth)-100);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it now, the text shows up for a frame and then goes to the top with the meteor it is linked to.

Comment: I think the issue on the demo is that the text is only printed for a frame and then not printed at all (I couldn't see it at the top of the screen). My suggestion is to store a side array of "scores" that don't fall and every time a collision occurs you add an entry to that array and schedule it's removal (in X seconds). Then in the game update cycle just iterate through the array and draw whatever is in there

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your answer! I'm not that profound in JS yet, but how would you recommend to store those coordinates? That's my problem.

Comment: Well, I would create an empty array at the same level as the `meteors` array you populate at setup. Something like `scores` would work. Then in the collision check instead of calling `text("-3", minScoreIndicatorX, minScoreIndicatorY);` I would add an item to said array `scores.push({text: "-3", x: minScoreIndicatorX, y: minScoreIndicatorY})`. Then somewhere in your draw function, iterate through the `scores` array and call `text` with the data of the items in there. Tell me if you manage it by yourself or if you need more code.

Comment: I took the liberty of grabbing your code from the live example and added the working parts [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2od73uw8/1/) you can see what I added right after NEWCODE comments

Comment: Thank you Carlos! This works perfectly. You are amazing. I still don't fully understand it but I'll dig deeper to get it! Thanks again, hero!

Comment: The only thing that does not work is the timeout, the numbers stay forever. Did this happen on your side too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I explained in the comments the solution is to create another global variable `scores` and on collision add an entry and schedule it's removal. And in the draw phase just render whatever text is in the scores array.

I've made a fiddle with the full javascript code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ryp76v8n/2/)

I checked that code and I noticed a small typo on line 35. Where it read `var scoreTTL = 3000;` should be `var scoresTTL = 3000;` (Note the missing "s")
(Updated fiddle to reflect it)

If you have any doubt about the code or the logic behind it I'm happy to explain it in a more detailed manner.

Hope it helped!

EDIT: the timeout was missing some code (line 223) changed fiddle link